# How can I store user input in arrays and then print them out?

Tags: java

I am a beginner programmer and I am making a little application for practice.

You enter your budget, then you add an expense(name, amount)
and it subtracts and tells you your current budget.

I want to make it so you can see all of your expenses after each execution.

I have tried to make for loops that store the names of the expenses and then print them.
But I am doing something wrong :/.

Sorry for my bad English, I am from Croatia!

Here is some beginner ugly code.

```
 int length = 0;
 String[] listOfNames = new String[length]; 

 boolean active = true;
 int budget = 0; 
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //user input

 System.out.println("Enter current budget in HRK");
 int enteredAmount = input.nextInt(); //user input for budget

 budget = enteredAmount;



 while(active)
 {
     System.out.println("Current budget is " + budget +  " HRK");
     System.out.println("Enter expense name and amount");

     System.out.println("Name: ");
     String name = input.next(); //name of expense


     for(int i=0; i<listOfNames.length;i++){ //adds entered expense names to array

     listOfNames[i] = name;
     length++;              
     }


     System.out.println("Amount: ");

     int enteredAmount1 = input.nextInt();

     budget -= enteredAmount1; // subtracts the budget from the users input

     System.out.println("Expense: " + name + ", Amount: " + enteredAmount1); // prints final result

     for(int j=0; j<listOfNames.length; j++) // prints stored strings in array
     {
       System.out.println(listOfNames[j]);
     }


 }
```

}
}

Comment: It appears you're doing both.  Not certain what the problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you save user input inside an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495000/how-do-you-save-user-input-inside-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

## Here are the issues:

1. You started the length of `listOfNames` at zero.

   ```
   int length = 0;
   String[] listOfNames = new String[length];
   ```

That's why the for loops never run.

2. Also, it is not possible to change the size of an array in Java. 
   To store a variable amount of input, I recommend an ArrayList, which can be resized.

   ```
   ArrayList<String> listOfNames = new ArrayList<String>();
   ```

Adding something to `listOfNames`:

```
    String name = input.next();
    listOfNames.add(name);
```

The downside to an ArrayList is that it is less efficient than an array, but this doesn't really matter for your program.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and another [helpful website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arraylist-in-java/) for ArrayLists.